# Change format of forwarded email with Outlook rules

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003

Is it possible to change the format of a forwarded email when using Outlook rules?
The ultimate result would be pull data from a regularly received pre-formated email and generate a basic forward with the select data.

Answer (score 0):

If you study the basics of Visual Basic, which as the name says aren't that hard, [you could use macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa209971(v=office.11).aspx).